# Terraform one EC2 instance with two subnets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I need to create one EC2 and associate 2 subnets to it.

**variables.tf**

```
variable "aws_subnet_id_this" {
  description = "Subnet ID"
  default = ["subnet-09df122a4faee8882", "subnet-2fcc756f02ddb4b62"]
}
```

**main.tf**

```
resource "aws_instance" "test" {
  ami                         = var.ami_id
  instance_type               = var.ec2_instance_type
  subnet_id                   = var.aws_subnet_id_this
  key_name                    = var.pki_name
  vpc_security_group_ids      = [aws_security_group.Allow_SSH_in.id]
}
```

**Error:**

> Error: Incorrect attribute value type
>
> on main_count_data.tf line 57, in resource "aws_instance" "test":
> 57:   subnet_id                   = var.aws_subnet_id_this
> |----------------
> | var.aws_subnet_id_eks is tuple with 2 elements
>
> Inappropriate value for attribute "subnet_id": string required.

So I tried this:

**main.tf**

```
resource "aws_instance" "prueba" {
  ami                         = var.ami_id
  instance_type               = var.ec2_instance_type
  #subnet_id                   = var.aws_subnet_id_this
  count = 2
  subnet_id = "${element(var.aws_subnet_id_this, count.index)}"
  key_name                    = var.pki_name
  vpc_security_group_ids      = [aws_security_group.Allow_SSH_in.id]
  }
}
```

but this last portion of code tries to create a new EC2 instance with the second subnet and this is not what I expect tough.

**To sum up:   I need 1 EC2 containing 2 subnets defined in the variables.tf file.**

How can I do this?

Comment: So you wish for 1 instance with two NICs? One of the nics shoud be in different subnet then the instance?

Comment: @Marcin, correct.

Comment: I modified the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is an example of how you can create one instance with two NICs in different subnets. The NICs **must** be in same AZ. So instance can have two NICs in different subnets as long as they are in same AZ:

```
variable "aws_subnet_id_this" {
  description = "Subnet ID"
  default = ["subnet-09df122a4faee8882", "subnet-2fcc756f02ddb4b62"]
}

resource "aws_network_interface" "nic1" {
  subnet_id       = var.aws_subnet_id_this[0]
}

resource "aws_network_interface" "nic2" {
  subnet_id       = var.aws_subnet_id_this[1]
}


resource "aws_instance" "prueba" {
  ami                         = var.ami_id
  instance_type               = var.ec2_instance_type
  key_name                    = var.pki_name

  network_interface {
      device_index = 0
      network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.nic1.id
  }
        
  network_interface {
      device_index = 1
      network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.nic2.id
  }  
  
}
```

Comment: Well, you can have a server with 2 nics, each of them on its own subnet. Common case example?  A server acting as a router between 2 subnets. You enable ip_forwarding and done.     ( I don't want a router tough, I just need my instance to be able to talk on different subnets.

Comment: @pedro Yes. Nic can be in different subnets. But instance is still in only one. Please update your question to make it clear that you are asking for nics, not instance. Or instance with two nics.

Comment: Thank you Sir, your code worked like a charm!  Only thing I had to deal with - but did it successfully - was with the addition of a SG.  So had to add: "security_groups = [aws_security_group.Allow_SSH_in.id]" into the "aws_network_interface" resource and then reference it later on the "network_interface" argument sub-block.

Comment: @pedro No problem. SGs are for NICs in this case, not the instance itself.