# Terraform create multiple ec2 instances in multiple subnets

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, subnet

I am trying to create multiple ec2 instances with access to multiple subnets.

I've found questions and answers on doing these things individually, but not combined.

First, I create a private and a public subnet, then I setup a local to store the IDs once they are created:

```
locals {
  subnets =  [ aws_subnet.public_subnet.id, aws_subnet.private_subnet.id ]
}
```

Next, I can create a variable number of servers in the `private_subnet` using `for_each` and the below:

```
servers = [ "s1", "s2" ]
resource "aws_instance" "system" {
  for_each                    = var.servers 
  ami                         = var.aws_ami
  instance_type               = var.instance_type
  #subnet_id                  = aws_subnet.private_subnet.id
  count = 2
  subnet_id                   = element(local.subs, count.index)
}
```

What I want to have, is that the server can access both subnets (it doesn't exist as far as I can tell, but the equivalent of `subnet_ids = [aws_subnet.public_subnet.id, aws_subnet.private_subnet.id]`).

I found a nice answer which works for a specific instance by creating two NICs ([Terraform one EC2 instance with two subnets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66361695/terraform-one-ec2-instance-with-two-subnets)), however I need to do this `var.servers` times so it's difficult to hardcode the `var.servers * 2` NICs with my current `aws_instance` setup (and I trip up when combining `for_each` and `count`).

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Your question is not clear. A server in a single subnet have access to all subnets in same VPC. So what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: In one subnet, I have for example two instances. I want one instance to be accessible inbound from the internet (with an internet gateway) and the other to only have outbound internet access (with a nat gateway). I thought the best way to do this would be to have a public and private subnet - is there a better way?

Comment: That's correct, so you place s1 in public subnet, and s2 in private subnet. So your question is about that?

Comment: Thanks Marcin, I understand the theory and can do it 'manually' in the console (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Scenario2.html) , but trying to automate that process with Terraform. I want to create a variable number of ec2 instances, which have NICs in both in the public and private subnets.

Comment: Why do you need two NICs for each instance? Your description does not indicate the need for two NICs. Two instances with one NIC each, should be enough.

Comment: How would I be able to assign the `aws_instance` above to both the `aws_subnet.public_subnet.id` and `aws_subnet.private_subnet.id` subnets on a single NIC?

Comment: But why? Your description " I want one instance to be accessible inbound from the internet (with an internet gateway) and the other to only have outbound internet access (with a nat gateway)." does not require such a setup.

Comment: I also want the instances to be able to communicate over rfc918 and not over the internet. Is it possible to have the internet gateway/nat gateway setup for separate machines on the same single subnet? I thought the route table could only have one 0.0.0.0/0 (either the internet gateway/nat gateway, not both) - which is why I am trying to create the separate subnets

Comment: Regardless, what does it mean "(and I trip up when combining for_each and count)"? Your question does not include such code? What exactly it is? What errors you get?

Comment: I updated the question to show what I was trying to do. The error: "Error: Invalid combination of "count" and "for_each""

Comment: The code does not create any NICs. Your instances will just have 1 NIC, not two. Have you tried creating the two NICs?

Comment: Yes. It's the same problem I don't know how to solve with Terraform. Need to combine a count (2 subnets) with a for_each (each ec2 instance).

Comment: I will give you the answer, but you end up with 4 instances. Sadly your code does not make any sense if you want to have 2 NICs for each instance and only 2 instances. You have to carefully review what you want to do.

Comment: I am new to Terraform, so appreciate if you can point me in the right direction for the outcome state I want.

Comment: I have it working, but not using your snippet. I don't want 4 servers. I will update with an answer.

Comment: Exactly as I told you. Your question is not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: Yes, it is clear you do not understand it. But it is solved, see the solution below.

Comment: No. The fact that no one else tried to reply nor even comment, means people simply gave up on your question. I'm am the only one that tried to help you.

Answer (score 1):

For those looking to have a similar setup there are a few steps (assuming subnets and route tables already exist):

- Create a machine on a single subnet
- Create an additional network interface
- Attach the network interface to the 'other' subnet (for the existing machine)

Create a variable for machines to create:

```
domains = [
  "asd.com",
  "asd2.com"
]
```

Create the machines on a single subnet:

```
resource "aws_instance" "domain" {
  for_each                    = var.domains
  ami                         = var.aws_ami
  subnet_id                   = aws_subnet.public_subnet.id
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  tags = {
    Name           = "Instance - ${each.key}"
  }
}
```

Create the additional interfaces for the 'other' subnet:

```
resource "aws_network_interface" "nics" {
  for_each          = var.domains
  subnet_id         = aws_subnet.private_subnet.id
  tags = {
    Name           = "NIC - ${each.key}"
  }
}
```

Attach the network interfaces to the 'other' subnet (for the existing machine):

```
resource "aws_network_interface_attachment" "attach_nics" {
  for_each              = var.domains
  instance_id           = aws_instance.domain[each.key].id
  network_interface_id  = aws_network_interface.nics[each.key].id
  device_index          = 1 # public_subnet = 0
}
```

The 'trick' here (that I didn't know) is understanding that you can access data from created resources based on their names in the existing script (which is used in the `aws_network_interface_attachment` component).

Answer (score 0):

Two create multiple servers (in your case 4 in total) in private (two servers) and public (two servers) subnets you can use `count`:

```
resource "aws_instance" "system" {
  count                    = length(var.servers) * length(local.subnets)
  ami                         = var.aws_ami
  instance_type               = var.instance_type
  subnet_id                   = element(local.subnets, count.index)
}
```